# boostrap 4 img-fluid strechs image on mobile resolution

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive

i need an image responsive width 100% with responsive component.
When i use :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="images/centre-mob.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
</div>
```

image will strech. Width is responsive but not height.

And when i use :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <img src="images/centre-mob.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

responsive is fine, but i have gutters on the left and right

And finally :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-12">
            <img src="images/centre-mob.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

is not a solution for gutters too...

the right solution would be :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="images/centre-mob.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

but in that case, gutters exist. And i need no padding at all...

I don't know how to do it... and it works fine on Firefox but not Chrome

any help ?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Use your second code sample and add a new class to reset the padding from col-12:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 padding-reset">
            <img src="images/centre-mob.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.padding-reset {
   padding: 0;
}
```